# Simultaneous similarity of two complex matrices and their hermitian conjugates implies their unitary similarity

Tags: unitary-matrices, similar-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two similar complex $n \times n$ matrices, i.e., there exists $P \in GL(\mathbb{C},n)$ such that $A=P B P^{-1}$. Furthermore, suppose that $A^{*} = P B^{*} P^{-1}$, where $M^{*}$ designates the conjugate transpose of a complex matrix $M$. I would like to show that $A$ and $B$ are unitarily similar.
I know one can easily get relations between real matrices by addition and subtraction of the two equations, but I don't see where unitarity would come from. I also tried to us the polar decomposition ($P=U H$, with $U$ unitary and $H$ Hermitian positive definite) but I don't see how to get rid of $H$ then. Only basic linear algebra if possible and, if necessary, only basic topology, please.
I hope I interpreted my textbook problem correctly : it says "$A$ and $A^{*}$ are simultaneously similar to $B$ and $B^*$". I am originally a physicist but now also an amateur mathematician (using * instead of + :-).

Comment: There is a way to do it with this result called [Specht's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht%27s_theorem) and seeing that $W(A,A^*) = PW(B,B^*)P^{-1}$ for all words $W$ thanks to the simultaneous similarity condition, however we'll both agree that admitting such a theorem to prove a textbook problem is not really satisfactory, which is why I leave this as only a comment and not an anwser. Hoping someone else will find a more elementary proof!

Comment: Thank you @BrunoB, I think I can take it from here. Indeed, I saw that the first part of Specht's proof of his theorem (a reference in your reference), which is also the difficult part, establishes precisely the simultaneous similarity, and the second part is something I can understand. So I'll try to edit the answer to my question myself, with reference to (the second part of) Spechts original proof :-)

Answer (score 2):

As announced in my answer to Bruno B's comment, the second part of Specht's original proof to his theorem contains the answer to my question. So I just adapt it here.

By taking  the Hermitian conjugate of $A=PBP^{-1}$, we obtain $P^{*-1} B^{*} P^{*}=A^{*}$. Therefore,
$P B^{*} P^{-1} = P^{*-1} B^{*} P^{*} $ or
$P^{*} P B^{*} = B^{*} P^{*} P $. Since $P^{*} P$ is similar to a diagonal matrix with only strictly positive eigenvalues, $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, there exists a matrix $H$, similar to a diagonal matrix with elements $\sqrt{\lambda_1},\dots,\sqrt{\lambda_n}$, and satisfying $H^2 = P^{*} P$.

Since there exists a real polynomial $p$ such that $p(\lambda_i) = \sqrt{\lambda_i}$, for all $i=1,\dots, n$, $H$ is a polynomial of $P^{*} P$ and therefore commutes with $B$.

Now, we define $U=H^{-1} P^{*}$, which is unitary, because $U U^{*} = H^{-1} P^{*} P H^{-1} = H^{-1} H^2 H^{-1} = 1$, to obtain finally,
$A=PBP^{-1}=U^{*} H B H^{-1} U = U^{*} B  U$.